# Insert a new redirect URI into Azure App Registration via Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have a powershell script to insert a new redirect URI through powershell. If I run the commands one by one, it works whereas if I run the script with the parameters, it doesnt work. Please help.

This is my script.

```
#######################################################################################
#Create New Redirect URI in Azure App Service:
#######################################################################################
param
(
    [string] $url,
    [string] $objectId,
    [string] $clientId,
    [string] $tenantValue,
    [string] $clientSecret,
    [string] $serviceAccountEmail,
    [string] $serviceAccountPassword
)

$webServiceURL = $url
Write-Host "$webServiceURL"
Write-Host "Done creating the webServiceURL"

Write-Host "Convert password to Secure string"
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $serviceAccountPassword -AsPlainText -Force
Write-Host "Done converting password to Secure string"

$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($serviceAccountEmail, $SecurePassword)

Write-Host "Logging in"
Login-AzAccount -Credential $Credential

$tid = (Get-AzTenant).Id

Write-Host "Getting token"
$tokenBody = @{
    'tenant' = $tid
    'client_id' = $clientId
    'scope' = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    'client_secret' = $clientSecret
    'grant_type' = 'client_credentials'
}

$Params = @{
    'Uri' = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tid/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    'Method' = 'Post'
    'Body' = $tokenBody
    'ContentType' = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

$AuthResponse = Invoke-RestMethod @Params

$AuthResponse


$header = @{
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
    'Authorization' = "Bearer $($AuthResponse.access_token)"
}

$header

$redirectUris = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/$objectId" -Headers $header).spa.redirectUris

if ($redirectUris -notcontains "$webServiceURL") {
    $redirectUris += "$webServiceURL"
    Write-Host "Adding $webServiceURL to redirect URIs";
}


$body = @{
    'spa' = @{
        'redirectUris' = $redirectUris
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/$objectId" -Headers $header -Body $body

Write-Host "Were there errors? (If the next line is blank, then no!) $error"
```

This is my screenshot where it is working if I enter commands step by step:

[image]

This is the screenshot where error occurs if I send it as parameters and execute the script file.

[image]

Do I need to wait on each step to get resolved and then proceed forward? Please advice.

Comment: In the error output, is the `SubscriptionName` value the correct one?

Comment: Yeah, they are.

Comment: Looking at the second image, you seem to use double-quotes on all parameter values you are sending. We cannot see the actual values of course, but it could be that something in there is regarded as for instance a variable when it is prefixed with the `$` sign and that resolves as $null.  Try using single quotes so all strings are sent as-is.

Comment: Tried that now. Same error.

Comment: Hello @a2441918, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue by providing a wrong `clientId`, which is not a part of tenant I am logging into.

[image]

So as solution you have to pass correct `clientId` which is residing in your tenant for your code to succesfully run like below.

[image]

**Update**

Reproduce 403 forbidden error

[image]

**Solution** : ***Added API persmission-> Application.ReadWrite.All for Microsoft Graph under Application Permission***.

[image]

Output :
[image]

Comment: My bad, sorry. I had misplaced objectId with clientId. It works fine now. I do get a 403 when I am patching. Any idea?

Comment: Try to Add API persmission "Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy, Application.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All" for Microsoft Graph->Apllication Permission. Check then

Comment: @a2441918 Update the answer please check.